# The Authentication on ASP.NET Core Not Work in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I learned Any Code and make a simple website using ASP.NET Core and the web site is working fine, but want to know how to test the web in local IIS. The web site is running without an error and showing the login page, but if I am loging the web is refresh only. My Login page url is "https://localhost/Identity/Account/Login"
and after I enter username password and click login button, url return into "https://localhost/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FError"

I don't know where the error because error is not visible.
following is my Web.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MySimple Project.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        <add connectionString="Server=localhost;Integrated Security=true" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Set the `stdoutLogEnabled="true" ` and then you could see the logs in the define log file path `.\logs\stdout`.Do you use asp.net core `Identity`?If you are testing authentication, what is your database?I mean where is your user table located?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i actually configure the SQL Server and add NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL Service and now its working fine. but, the website show invalid certivicate. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What is the type of your certificate?A self-signed certificate or other certificate you have bought.Not familiar with that...

Comment: I'm not using any certificate, just only default IIS Development certificate. I really don't know about certificate and not have any documentation about that